# Using Spring data with PagingAndSortingRepository and IgniteRepository is throwing error

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, ignite

I am working on a spring data project and tying to integrate Ignite cache with it.
I was using already using PagingAndSortingRepository<Entity, String>

```
   @Repository public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, String> {
    
        Page<User> findByUserId(final String userId, final Pageable pageable);
    
        Page<User> findByFirstName(final String firstName, final Pageable pageable);
    
        Page<User> findByEmailAddress(final String emailAddress, final Pageable pageable);
            
        Page<User> findAllBy(final Pageable pageable); 
}
```

and I added a new Repository IgniteRepository<Entity, String>

```
@RepositoryConfig(cacheName = "UserCache")
public interface UserCacheRepository extends IgniteRepository<UserCacheDto, String> {

    @Query("select UserCacheDto FROM UserCacheDto WHERE userId = ?")
    List<UserCacheDto> findByUserId(final String userId);

    @Query("select UserCacheDto FROM UserCacheDto WHERE firstName = ?")
    List<UserCacheDto> findByFirstName(final String firstName);

    @Query("select UserCacheDto FROM UserCacheDto WHERE emailAddress = ?")
    List<UserCacheDto> findByEmailAddress(final String emailAddress);

}
```

The idea behind this setup was to fetch from the database only when the data is not found in cache

Below are my project dependencies

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.src.portal</groupId>
<artifactId>portalDataBaseCacheModule</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>portalDataBaseCacheModule</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.version>2.5.4</spring.version>
    <ignite.version>2.9.0</ignite.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.200</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-spring-data_2.2</artifactId>
        <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
        <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-spring-boot-autoconfigure-ext</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-log4j2</artifactId>
        <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>18.3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Upon doing this integration I am getting the below compilation error,

> java: name clash: deleteAllById(java.lang.Iterable) in
> org.apache.ignite.springdata22.repository.IgniteRepository and
> deleteAllById(java.lang.Iterable<? extends ID>) in
> org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository have the same
> erasure, yet neither overrides the other

From the error it appears that somehow since both the repository are internally extending CrudRepository its causing an issue, I am not able to Figure out why and how to solve this issue.
Please help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your error `UserCacheRepository` inherits  `IgniteRepository.deleteAllById(Iterable<K> ids)` and  `CrudRepository.deleteAllById(Iterable<? extends ID> ids)`, but erasures for `Iterable<K>` and `Iterable<? extends ID>` would be the same (just `Iterable`), so we get into situation when class has two methods with absolutely same signatures and this lead to name clash error.

Root cause for this error is that `IgniteRepository` originally was written when `CrudRepository` didn't have `deleteAllById()` method, meanwhile `CrudRepository` that comes with modern versions of **spring-boot-starter-data-jpa** has this method.

You may try to use older version for spring data if it possible for rest of your application.

Also you mey try to explicitly override deleteAllById(Iterable iterable) method, but I'm not sure if it helps.

The best option is to update apache-ignite-extensions to work with latest spring data, so you can create a Jira ticket in Apache Ignite project for this.